# Field level permissions cache on multi-tenant Azure hosted ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Api

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Api multi-tenant Azure hosted system with a field level security. In this system each field (database column) has a corresponding row in another table which specifies read/write role permission for this field.

The problem which I am considering right now is a way of caching and accessing these permissions in real-time. Since almost every request must be checked by these permissions, I need to pull them from some cache, cause I don't think I should pull them from a database (additional trip to a database for each request could slow down entire system).

The system is hosted on serveral Azure centers (each for multiple number of clients) and more database instances (each for one client). Each client represents a group of users with their accounts and roles. The number of clients isn't great (about a dozen for a center) and the number of roles comes to maybe a dozen. So I must cache somewhere clients * client's roles * role permissions entities (maybe two hundreds) for real-time access.

Since I am doing all of this for a first time, I need an advice. Is Azure Redis Cache the only reliable option (if yes, then ok) or is there some other way?

Comment: Why not just load the permissions at startup and store them in memory?

Comment: You mean like in a static class object? Just like that?

Comment: Yep.  Just load the data into some collection and assign it to a static variable.

Comment: Ok. But what when someone modifies a permission so it will be necessary to update the static?